# How do I use a template-literal within hue-rotate()

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to JS but I came across this problem:

```
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random * 360);
document.getElementById('vanta').style.filter = "hue-rotate(${rand}deg)";
```

My idea was to rotate the hue randomly every time the user refreshes the page.
Is it possible to use a template literal like that? If not how are there other ways to randomly change the background color/hue in vanilla js/css.

Comment: You need backticks `  hue-rotate(${rand}deg) ` see the following link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need backticks `hue-rotate(${rand}deg)`
Try Math.random() as well.

```js
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 360);
document.getElementById('vanta').style.filter = `hue-rotate(${rand}deg)`;
```

```html
<div id="vanta" style="background:red">I am rotated red</div>
```